# Adding an extra thickness to a 3D model (not scaling)

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm just looking for the name of this geometrical transformation:

"adding/removing a thickness all around a 3D shape"

"Like plunging glasses in a pot of melted chocolate"

Another example:

"Having a model representing a piece of paper 100x100x0.1, and then adding an extra 1.0 will give a new model 102x102x2.1"

A scale won't do the job, I guess. What's the name of this operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding / remove a certain tickness to a PolyHedron's external shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563803/adding-remove-a-certain-tickness-to-a-polyhedrons-external-shape)

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, it's the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of the original shape and, most likely, a sphere.

It's relatively easy to implement between two convex shapes — at the absolute worst you can put an instance of one object's geometry at every vertex of the other and then take the convex hull of that*; therefore decomposing a concave shape into convex subsections and proceeding feels like a sufficiently effective way to proceed if you're on a time crunch.

(*) you can do save time on than that by locating faces on one object with normals in between those faces on the other, but it's harder. Or just grab [somebody else's solution](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_3/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to [thicken or offset](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/InventorLT-Help/files/GUID-32FB7E7C-A20D-4518-BD27-DBB2D8CF49B1-htm.html) a surface.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a lot of context, but in general, you would either be looking to scale or transform (which can scale) the geometry. If you're looking for a more specific case, you'll need to update your question.

I believe some CAD programs can create this using a shell operation with a negative distance.